# Really long class/variable/property/method names

Tags: naming-conventions, naming, variable-names, class-names

Some friends and colleagues of mine have a little running contest to find or write the longest class/variable/property/method names possible.  Keep in mind, we try to be good boys and girls and keep the naming intelligible and concise, while still explaining what the thing does via its name.

Sometimes it just doesn't happen though.  Have you run in to this?  I'd just like to see what's out there. (Maybe my friends and I aren't as crazy as we think)

Note: I'm not looking for **bad** naming. That's already [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143701/what-is-the-worst-classvariablefunction-name-you-have-ever-encountered).  I'm looking for **good** naming that just got a little long.

Comment: Oracle doesn't let one play this game. 32 chars max still, and we are living in 2008!

Comment: a huge name is probably a bad name, for the simple fact that if you need a huge name to describe what it does then it is most likely doing too much ;)

Comment: @workmad3 Too True! Not being able to name a function correctly is usually the symptom of another problem, it does too much!

Comment: While having long class names can indicate loose coupling, breaking down functionality in seperate classes. e.g. Having worker classes for subclasses ... n ... of a model.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This isn't a class name but an enum, but it's a lot longer:

```
VirtualMachineDeviceRuntimeInfoVirtualEthernetCardRuntimeStateVmDirectPathGen2InactiveReasonOther
```

from the VMware vSphere API. Google for it and you'll find the online documentation.

Answer (score 12):

It isn't really long but my favorite variable name ever was to indicate that a user had opted in to receive email.

> User.IsSpammable

Comment: If you are not too obsessed with booleans starting with "is", you could do User.canSpam

Answer (score 8):

I find it's nice to have long test names which describe the test. For instance:

```
testMapWithOneEntryAllowsDifferentEntryPreservingFirst
testMapWithOneEntryAllowsDuplicateEntryOverwritingFirst
```

(These are just examples off the top of my head... you get the idea though.)

Answer (score 7):

```
org.aspectj.weaver.patterns;

public class HasThisTypePatternTriedToSneakInSomeGenericOrParameterizedTypePatternMatchingStuffAnywhereVisitor {
    boolean ohYesItHas = false;

    public boolean wellHasItThen/*?*/() {
        return ohYesItHas;
    }

    ... more methods...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Some times ago, I had a problem with Hibernate.
I got a NullPointerException in the method called findIntendedAliasedFromElementBasedOnCrazyJPARequirements !

Answer (score 3):

```
protected virtual OcrBarcodeSymbologies GetSupportedBarcodeSymbologies() { }
```

Answer (score 2):

The excellent [GTK+](http://www.gtk.org/) library "suffers" from this. It has very neatly named functions, but since the main API is C, and GTK+ is very object-oriented, it must encode class names in the functions name. The constructor for class X is X_new(), and so on. This leads to beaties such as [gtk_recent_chooser_widget_new_for_manager()](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/stable/GtkRecentChooserWidget.html#gtk-recent-chooser-widget-new-for-manager).

I'm sure there are even longer function names in there, this was just one that I found quickly. :)

Answer (score 2):

Long variable names don't bother me as long as there's not an obvious more concise name and the naming is sane.  For instance, in Kamaelia, there's a class type named this:

```
threadedadaptivecommscomponent
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out Apple's documentation. They're kings at that. Very descriptive, but sometimes miles long. A couple of examples from the NSString class:

```
NSString.completePathInfoString:caseSensitive:matchesToArray:filterType
NSString.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding
```

My favourite in the Microsoft world: `SetProcessWorkingSetSize`

Answer (score 1):

In the apple mail app:

```
_synchronouslyTellServicesToRegisterAndSync()
```

In a app I wrote:

```
User.CanViewRestrictedItems()
```

I an app a colleague wrote:

```
Profile.DisplayMyDraftOrPendingProfile()
Profile.DisplayMyApprovedProfile()
```

Just to get started.

**new:**

A foreign key constraint name:

```
constraint ReportCompanyReportTemplateIDVersionID_ReportTemplateVersionReportTemplateIDVersionIDFk foreign key (ReportTemplateID, VersionID) references customer_ReportTemplateVersion (ReportTemplateID, VersionID)
```

Answer (score 1):

A naming convention I've seen, years before fluent became en vogue

```
public DataSet SelectAllUsersWhereDobIsGreaterThan1980AndIsMaleOrderByNameAndAge()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
bool instrumentAreaDockWidgetVisibilityFollowsChildPresence;
```

Answer (score 0):

get the `js` items that will be retrieved and if page should display recommendations.